# Weird behaviour of C program in MacOS

Tags: c, macos, fork

I've been writing a shell program in C. The program is working as expected in Linux (Ubuntu 16.04) but I'm getting unexpected output in MacOS (10.14.2 Mojave).

```C
/* A shell program.
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>


void input(char* argv[]);
void print_arr(char *argv[]); // For debugging

int
main(void)
{
    while (1)
    {
        pid_t pid;
        char *argv[100];

        // Display shell prompt
        write(1, "(ash) $ ", 8);

        // Take user input
        input(argv);
        // print_arr(argv); // DEBUG STATEMENT

        if (argv[0] != NULL)
        {
            // Exit if exit command is entered
            if (strcmp(argv[0], "exit") == 0)
            {
                exit(0);
            }

            // Create child process
            if ((pid = fork()) > 0)
            {
                wait(NULL);
            }
            else if (pid == 0)
            {
                // print_arr(argv); // DEBUG STATEMENT

                execvp(argv[0], argv);
                printf("%s: Command not found\n", argv[0]);
                exit(0);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Fork Error!\n");
            }
        }       
    }
}


/* Takes input from user and splits it in
   tokens into argv. The last element in
   argv will always be NULL. */
void
input(char* argv[])
{
    const int BUF_SIZE = 1024;
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];
    int i;

    buf[0] = '\0';
    fgets((void*) buf, BUF_SIZE, stdin);

    i = 0;
    argv[i] = strtok(buf, "  \n\0");
    while (argv[i] != NULL)
    {
        argv[++i] = strtok(NULL, "  \n\0");
    }
}

/* Print argv for debugging */
void
print_arr(char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0;
    while (argv[i] != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d: %s\n", i, argv[i]);
        ++i;
    }
}
```

In Linux:

```
(ash) $ ls
// files and folders are listed
```

In MacOS (with debug statements):

```
(ash) $ ls
0: p?M??
0: ??M??
: Command not found
(ash) $ ls
0: ls
0: ??M??
: Command not found
(ash) $ ls
0: ls
0: ??M??
```

I don't understand that why are the contents of `char* argv[]` getting modified across `fork()`?

I've also tried it in the default `clang` compiler and brew's `gcc-4.9`, the results are same.

Comment: The `input` function stores pointers to the ***local*** array `buf` in `argv`. After the function returns, all those pointers will become invalid.

Comment: In addition to the bug Someprogrammerdude mentioned, isn't the EOL character '\r' in Mac instead of '\n'?

Comment: @BobShaffer On old MacOS before X.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks! I got it working now by passing `buf` in `input()` function. Any idea why was it working in Ubuntu? Something related to unspecified behavior?

Comment: @AdityaVerma Yes, undefined behavior is the reason for that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I wondered if it changed there since it's built on BSD or something now.

Comment: a quick workaround could be qualifiying the `buf` array as `static`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a program behaves different for no good reason, that's a VERY good sign of undefined behavior. And it is also the reason here.

The array `buf` is local to the function `input` and ceases to exist when the function exits.

One way of solving this is to declare `buf` in `main` and pass it to `input`. You will also need the size of the buffer for `fgets`.

```
void
input(char * argv[], char * buf, size_t size)
{
    buf[0] = '\0';
    fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);

    argv[0] = strtok(buf, "  \n\0");

    for(int i=0; argv[i] != NULL; i++) argv[i+1] = strtok(NULL, "  \n\0");
}
```

Another solution (although I suspect many will frown upon it) is to declare `buf` as `static`, but then you would need to change `BUF_SIZE` to a `#define` or a hard coded value, since you cannot have a static VLA.

```
#define BUF_SIZE 1024
void
input(char * argv[])
{
    static char buf[BUF_SIZE];

    buf[0] = '\0';
    fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);

    argv[0] = strtok(buf, "  \n\0");

    for(int i=0; argv[i] != NULL; i++) argv[i+1] = strtok(NULL, "  \n\0");
}
```

I removed the cast to `void*` since it's completely unnecessary. I also changed the while loop to a for loop to make the loop variable local to the loop.

Comment: Thank you for providing better coding guidelines and alternate ways to solve the problem. However, my queries were resolved in the comments section itself. Should I mark this answer as accepted answer?

Comment: @AdityaVerma If you choose to do so it's up to you, but it is nothing wrong or even unusual to do so.

Comment: Hey @Broman, today I found that your `for` loop isn't actually correct. When you start with `i=1`, it checks `argv[1]` to not be `NULL` whereas we need it to check for `i=0`. So I guess, `while` loop is the way to go.

Comment: @AdityaVerma Mistake from me. I've fixed it. It was not because it was a for loop. Just a stupid mistake. You can ALWAYS transform a while loop to a for loop and vice versa.

Comment: Ah, got it. Thanks again :)

Comment: @AdityaVerma In this particular case it did not add much, and I don't know if it was worth the effort. But I do believe in encapsulation when possible. However, you can achieve the same effect with curly braces like this: `{int i=0; while (argv[i] != NULL) { ... }}` but people might find that confusing. That's why I usually use a for loop instead.

Comment: The biggest design thing I wanted to get rid of was that you ALSO used `i` to access the first element before the loop. That did not make sense.